# select/option tags and their id

Tags: javascript, html

I have many `select` tags, and when user clicks one of the `option` tags, I want to get `id` of `select` element, where clicked on `option`.

How I can do this?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What exactly do you not know how to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Show us your html code, and what you tried, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event:

```js
document.querySelector('#mySelect').addEventListener('change', function() {
   console.log(this.value);
   console.log(this.id);
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

To scale this for multiple elements, define your function outside of the event, iterate over your selects and attach the event listener to them:

```
function selectChange() {
   console.log(this.value);
   console.log(this.id);
}

var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
   selects[i].addEventListener('change', selectChange, false);
}
```

Comment: This is getting the value not the ID and this also wouldn't work for multiple `select`s *"I have many select tags" " I want to get id of select element"*

Comment: You can also get the id of the select, updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload=function(){
 selects=document.getElememtsByTagName("select");
 for(i=0;i<selects.length;i++){
     selects[i].onchange=function(){
         var select=this.id;
         var value=this.value;
         var option=this.parentElement.id;
        //do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: Don't use onclick, the event will fire when just opening up the select menu, use onchange

Comment: @squint: using stackexchange app...

Comment: @Patrick Evans: o yeah right, thank you

Comment: Thank you, but through events, I more likes

Comment: @mrchebik : thats through events, i use a not so common way assigning a function to the onchange property of an element

Comment: You should avoid defining functions within loops, it is expensive to create function contexts (especially when there is no variance in the function). It also makes it more difficult to remove event listeners from individual `<select>`s

Comment: @Rob M. O yeah thank you for that advise

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option id="o1">1</option>
    <option id="o2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option id="o1">3</option>
    <option id="o2">4</option>
</select>

<select id="select3">
    <option id="o1">5</option>
    <option id="o2">6</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

window.onload=function()
{
    $(document).on("change","select",function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
   })
}
```